# find_all() method of BS4 not capturing everything

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote this code to extract the past filmography of filmmaker, Ken Loach. I wanted the past work of the filmmaker as a director which includes 56 entries, so I targeted the `<ul>` tag by applying `find()` method which worked but when I tried to target all the `<li>` tags under it, which are supposed to be 56, I get only 15! Below is my code:

```
url="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0516360/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0"
hdr = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
resp=requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
html=resp.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
uls=soup.find('ul', 'ipc-metadata-list ipc-metadata-list--dividers-between ipc-metadata-list--base')
films=uls.find_all('li', 'ipc-metadata-list-summary-item ipc-metadata-list-summary-item--click sc-139216f7-1 fFMbUG')
print(len(films))
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

PS: I'm learning Web-scraping and I am a beginner at it.

Answer (score 0):

`Soup` is empty problem is that. Use cookie and accept in your headers. Also you have to click view all for all films. You can do it with `selenium` or `playwright`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
head = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Cookie': 'session-id=140-8492617-3903853; session-id-time=2082787201l; csm-hit=tb:7VKG5AZH38ZHJTWZ0TDQ+s-7VKG5AZH38ZHJTWZ0TDQ|1675775852695&t:1675775852695&adb:adblk_no',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
}
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0516360/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0'
r = requests.get(url, headers=head)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
lists = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'ipc-metadata-list-summary-item ipc-metadata-list-summary-item--click sc-139216f7-1 fFMbUG')
for z in lists:
    print(z.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the page only contains 15 links to begin with. It loads up more dynamically when you click the button to show more.
You can manually check this through "view page source" button in your browser.
You can use selenium or any other JS rendering service to access the page and simulate user clicks.